# Async call and not wait while using pubnub with django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, asynchronous, pubnub

This is a module from PubNub that I'm using to publish a message to a topic from an API. By design I've kept the PubNub object singleton.

```
class Pubnub:
    instance = None

    @classmethod
    def get(cls):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = cls()
        return cls.instance

    def __init__(self):
        with open('config/config.yaml', 'r') as stream:
            try:
                conf = yaml.load(stream)
                pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
                pnconfig.subscribe_key = conf['pubnub']['publish_key']
                pnconfig.publish_key = conf['pubnub']['subscribe_key']
                pnconfig.ssl = False
                self.pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)
            except yaml.YAMLError as e:
                logger.error(str(e))

    def publish(self, channel):
        try:
            envelope = self.pubnub.publish().channel(channel).message({
                'message': True
            }).sync()
            print("publish timetoken: %d" % envelope.result.timetoken)
        except PubNubException as e:
            logger.error(str(e))
```

This is how I'm calling it,

```
class SendCommunityTextMessage(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            client_id = request.GET['client_id']
            client_secret = request.GET['client_secret']
            if Authenticator.authenticate_client(client_id, client_secret):
                try:
                   //do something
                    try:
                        //do something more

                        pubbub = Pubnub.get()
                        pubbub.publish(receiver.hex_code)
                        return Response({"Success": CommunityTextMessageSerializer(message).data},
                                        status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                    except KeyError as e:
                        return Response({"Failure": str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                except (User.DoesNotExist, CommunityRoom.DoesNotExist) as e:
                    return Response({"Failure": str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

            else:
                return Response({"Failure": "Invalid client"}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        except KeyError as _:
            return Response({"Failure": "Probably a typo, read the docs to use this API."},
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The issue is this slows down the API by minutes. How can I call the two lines,

```
pubbub = Pubnub.get()
pubbub.publish(receiver.hex_code)
```

asynchronously and return out of the view without waiting for the call to finish.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Can you provide logs: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python-aiohttp/pubnub-python-sdk-troubleshooting-guide